# How to evolve local keyvaluestore schema

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

We have an application that uses Kafka streams to process data, we are using confluent registry and defining schemas in Avro format. We have a local key-value state named as paymentdetailstore say with the key as payementDTO which consists of payment id and payment source and the value is paymentValueDTO with payment details. now we want to introduce a new field in key, say orignator which can be null. If we do this change it will generate a new schema-id. now since schema-id is embedded in key during serialization and we will not be able to fetch the correct value making our existing data unusable. Is there any way to counter it without using version information in name.

Answer (score 1):

The AvroSerde class from Confluent already maintains its own ID cache; there's no reason to do that on your own.

If you build a SpecificRecord serde class and run your code with "version 2", then any "version 1" record in the topic will automatically be evolved.

Keep in mind that if you change the key, you're also changing partitioning scheme of the producer, which causes ordering issues in KStreams